# Make a http request in dart whith dart:io

Tags: dart, dart-http

Hey I'm a beginner and I want to interact with an API with dart:io for fetch JSON files I can fetch the data with this code :

```
  final HttpClient client = HttpClient();
  client.getUrl(Uri.parse("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/76341?api_key=fbe54362add6e62e0e959f0e7662d64e&language=fr"))
  .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
    return request.close();
  })
  .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
    Map a;
    print(a);
```

But I want to have a Map whith the JSON but I can't do it. If I could get a String that contains the JSON I could do it with
`json.decode();`

also know that the answer is stored in an int list that represents the utf8 values of the characters so with `utf8.decode(responce.toList())` I can get the utf8 value but `responce.toList()` return a Future but even if it may be easy I don't know how to get the list.

Comment: Hi Colin, What exactly is your question?

Comment: Yeah, what is your question can you explain a little bit more

Comment: Sorry it was just a test too now if the code is correctly formated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  final client = HttpClient();
  final request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(
      'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/76341?api_key=fbe54362add6e62e0e959f0e7662d64e&language=fr'));
  final response = await request.close();
  final contentAsString = await utf8.decodeStream(response);
  final map = json.decode(contentAsString);
  print(map);
}
```

Comment: Thanx you Alexandre